# How exactly should JWT-based authentication be implemented in Django (drf and simplejwt)?

Tags: python, django, authentication, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am struggling to understand exactly how JWT-based authentication should be implemented in Django (I am using simplejwt). I am just a beginner, so please brace yourselves for some silly questions. The rest-framework-simplejwt documentation is very minimal and does not provide enough detail for a newbie like me.

```
path('token/obtain', jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_create'),
path('token/refresh', jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
```

So, I've created the paths in my urls.py as suggested by the official documentation. Where do I go from here? I guess my confusion comes from the fact that I am not sure where exactly in the code I have to issue my tokens. Let's say, I am logging in the user. So, in order to obtain the token, do I have to send a request to the 'token_create' endpoint from inside my view? Or do I have to somehow indicate it in one of my serializers? What about the 'refresh_token' endpoint? Is there a specific method that I need to use?

Then, what do I do with the token once it has been issued? Clearly, I shouldn't save it in the database since it defeats the entire purpose of using JWTs in the first place. From my understanding, I should attach it to the headers so that the subsequent requests by the user contain the tokens in the headers.

The frontend will be written in ReactJS and will be on a separate server from my Django backend API, and the communication between the two will be configured through CORS.

In this case, how do I attach the token to the headers and make it so that the user's browser sends in the token with each request? Is there some sort of package that could be useful for that?

Comment: Does this help? https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/12/19/how-to-use-jwt-authentication-with-django-rest-framework.html

Comment: @HosseinHeydari, thanks for the response, but unfortunately, it doesn't :( What they do in that tutorial in order to issue a token is send a request directly to the 'token_create' and 'token_refresh' endpoints that I described above through the command line. I have already tried issuing direct requests through postman to issue tokens and using them to access protected views, and it works. What I am confused about, however, is how to implement this behavior in my Django app, e.g. whether I need to send a request from within the view using the "requests" module, how to set client headers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just mixed everything up, I'm gonna explain everything however you may already know some stuff.

JWT simply is a way to authorize users, you usually create an endpoint to create a token for the users, this endpoint can be named `login`, `create_token`, 'generate_token', or anything! doesn't really matter!

However maybe if u use a specific library maybe it forces you to use a specific endpoint but in `Flask` it's really what you like.

This `login` (whatever you call it) endpoint will take a username and password and checks if it exists and it's correct, then generates a `JWT` with a library like [PyJWT](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), You can configure the JWT to be expired in for example 20 mins or more, then you encrypt a `dictionary`(JSON?) which **usually** contains `user_id` which you query from the database. example of the JSON you provide to the user with:

```
{
  "user_id": something,
  "role": something,
  ...
}
```

Then it will be encrypted to a long string.

now when the user sends a request, he/she needs to have that long string as the `Authorization` header of the request.

In `postman --> Authorizations`, choose `Bearer Authorization` and then insert that long string.

**We also give the user a `refresh_token`**.

This is the example of the JSON you provide the user with when he/she calls the `login` endpoint:

```
{
 token: some_long_string,
 refresh_token: some_long_string,

}
```

**So what is refresh Token?**

it's just the token that when the main token expires instead of making the user enter username and password again, he just sends the refresh token we gave him while he called `login`.

One more point: This was the whole flow and logic you need to implement. Do it as you like, libraries or anything you like, doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am using the simplejwt library for my project and the installation guide requires me to create the endpoints that I included in my original question. Thus, I am confused by the technicalities of how I need to issue the token from inside my LoginView since it seems that the login and token_obtain endpoints need to be different.

Comment: Also, if I issue plain JSON with the tokens as a response to my user's request, wouldn't that be insecure?

Comment: Nope, it's not insecure, cause, later on, it has to be on HTTPS  protocol and it's safe.

Comment: The last question is the following: you mentioned how I can set up my authorization headers through postman and include my tokens in there to access protected views. I get that. I think where I am confused is that in a real-life scenario, users obviously do not need to copy and paste tokens to headers through their browser: everything just works automatically. So I am wondering how this functionality is enabled. Is there a specific package/framework that sets the headers? How do the JWT tokens go from the JSON response to the headers?

Comment: I suggest you stop using `SimpleJWT` if you have any problem with it, I can't help you cause I've never used it, simply use PyJWT and implement the logic yourself, much easier.

Comment: No, it doesn't work automatically, if you don't have a front-end then you need to teach your users to work with tools like `curl` or `postman`, but if you have a front-end! then after the user logins, his/her JWT will be saved in a `cookie` with `http-only` flag or `store`. the user never needs to understand how API works. it's all between you and your frontend.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will consider it. With PyJWT, is there a way to set up token blacklist functionality?

Comment: You don't need to blacklist JWT! simply put `created_at`  in your JWT, which is the current date and time, use `datetime.datetime.now()`. then there never be a duplicate JWT created.

Comment: How can logout be implemented then? Wouldn't it mean that the user cannot log out unless the token has expired?

Comment: You can set an expiration time to your token! but when the user logouts manually, that's a frontend developer task to remove the JWT from the `cookie` or `store`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you A LOT for your explanations! You really helped clear up so many things I was confused about. I really appreciate you taking your time to help!